# div is not executing inside table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 <table class="table">
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <tr>
 <td>
               <a href="#countdown" ></a>

                <div id="countdown" class="countdownHolder">
                    <span class="countDays">
                        <span class="position">
                            <span class="digit static"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="position">
                            <span class="digit static"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="countDiv countDiv3"></span>
                    </span>

                </div>
</td>
            </tr>

}
    </table>
```

This is my code. I need to execute the Div so that my jscript will be executed. But at runtime the Div get scipped. What should I do?

Comment: what is the Model, post Model and get action

Comment: SideNote: You are using `id="countdown"` in a foreach loop, that will create multiple div same id. __IDs in HTML must be unique__. Can you elaborate what do you mean be `execute the Div`. Why are you using foreach, when there is not a single reference to `item`

Comment: More info on the id/ class difference - http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: otherwise you can use `name` instead of `id`